# Decomposing a Combination of Distributions?

Tags: r, distributions, random-variable, lognormal-distribution

Let's say I'm studying the distribution/log-distribution of a random variable that may actually be the result of a combination of distributions.  What are the ways I can check for this and possibly get the component distributions?  Algorithms, pointers or software (e.g.: R packages) are all fine.

It's ok if these methods aren't completely accurate; I just need a starting point from which to analyze the results.

Comment: So you want to check if there exist $W,V$ such that your observation $Y$ fulfills $Y=W+V$?

Comment: I'm open to that and any other method.

Comment: Mixture distributions and distributions of sums are very distinct models. If you don't bother which model conveys the "Sachverhalt" of your data you are most likely to do numeromancy instead of statistics.

Comment: It's a mixture distribution I'm interested in -- distributions that are composites formed by being drawn from different populations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like "Fitting mixture distributions" ?

I found something with google, maybe it can help you : [Fitting mixture distributions with the R package mixtools](http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-the-r-package-mixtools/)

Comment: Yes, this is great!  I ran a plot using the example provided on both the value and the log, and got a graphical decomposition of the distributions in question!!!!